# Socket.io doesn't remove user object from array after disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
const socketUsers = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("user", (userdata) => {
        const aUser = { socket: socket, user: userdata };
        socketUsers.push(aUser);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        delete socketUsers[socket.id];
        console.log(socketUsers);
    });
});
```

The `socket` and `user` field is also assigned to the `aUser` then it's pushed into the `socketUsers` array. This happens after the user logs in because we need their userdata.

When the user disconnects, the console logs the array for me but the user is still there (both socket and userdata fields).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing the array wrong, pushing new sockets onto it won't make those sockets' ids be indexes of the array, from what i can tell you probably should use an object instead.

```
const socketUsers = {};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("user", (userdata) => {
        const aUser = { socket: socket, user: userdata };
        socketUsers[socket.id] = aUser;
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        delete socketUsers[socket.id];
        console.log(socketUsers);
    });
});
```

If you are so insistent on using an array, you would have to manually search it for index of the element you're looking for

```
const socketUsers = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("user", (userdata) => {
        const aUser = { socket: socket, user: userdata };
        socketUsers.push(aUser);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socketUsers.splice(socketUsers.findIndex(elem => elem.socket.id === socket.id), 1);
        console.log(socketUsers);
    });
});
```